# Find the image of the Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

My question is:

Find the image of the area $C=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z+3|\geq 3\}$ of the Möbius transformation $w=f(z)=\frac{z}{z+6}$.

I have drawn the image in the z-plane and then taken three points $z_{1},z_{2},z_{3}$ and then used the function for $w$ to get values for $w_{1},w_{2},w_{3}$. Then I have drawn the image for the w-plane. See figure. Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As HajJafar says, Mobius transformations map generalised circles to generalised circles. (A "generalised circle" is anything that is either a circle or a straight line.)

A generalised circle can be uniquely specified by specifying three points on it.

For example, the circle $C = \{z \in \mathbb C : |z + 3 | = 3 \} $ is the unique circle containing the three points $-3 +3i$, $0$ and $-3 - 3i$.

You have identified that your Mobius transformation maps $-3 +3i$, $0$ and $-3 - 3i$ to $i$, $0$ and $-i$ respectively. So the Mobius transformation must map the circle $C$ to the unique generalised circle passing through $i$, $0$ and $-i$.

The unique generalised circle passing through $i$, $0$ and $-i$ is easy to identify. It is the $y$-axis, $\{ z \in \mathbb C : {\rm Re}(z) = 0\}$.

[This is not the same thing as the line segment between $-i$ and $i$, which is what you drew on your picture.]

But you're asked to find the image of the region $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z + 3 | \geq 3 \}$. Observe that the point $z = 1$ is in this region, and it maps to the point $\frac 1 7$, which is on the right-hand side of the $y$-axis. The conclusion is that the image of $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z + 3 | = 3 \}$ is everything to the right-hand side of the $y$-axis, i.e. it is the region $\{ z \in \mathbb C : {\rm Re}(z) \geq 0 \}$.

Comment: It is possible that the drawing on the right hand side is actually a correct (if sketchy) depiction of the image of $C$. If the line segment between $-i$ and $i$ is indeed emphasized, and if the region between the lines $y=-1$ and $y=1$ has also been emphasized as the image of $C$, then the solution is wrong. However, that "emphasis" may only be an artifact of the sketching process. The OP may be able to tell us what the intent was supposed to be.

Comment: Sure. @math, if I misunderstood your drawing, then I do apologise!

Comment: I have drawn a line segment between $-i$ and $i$, since I got my $w_{1}=i, w_{2}=0, w_{3}=-i$ and then I thought that the image should be on the left hand side of this line segment. So this is wrong?

Comment: The circle $\{ z \in \mathbb C: | z + 3 | = 3 \}$ is not mapped onto the line segment between $-i$ and $i$. It is mapped onto the _entire $y$-axis._ You correctly identified that your chosen three points map to $i$, $0$ and $-i$. But other points from the circle get sent to other points on the $y$-axis, and some of them are sent to points outside the scope of the line segment between $-i$ and $i$. For example, the point $-6$ lies on the circle, and it gets sent to the point at infinity. And by the way, the image is on the _right-hand side_ of the line segment, as it shown in your picture! :-)

Comment: Suggestion: The point $-3 + 3 e^{3\pi i /4}$ lies on the circle. Work out where that Mobius transformation sends this point.

Comment: Okey so I was thinking correct when I chose the 3 points and found out the 3 points they where mapping. And these points I found are only a small fraction of the whole area since I only chose 3 points. And this means that the image area is the whole $Re(w)\geq 0$? Haha I mean the left hand side with respect to the arrows I have drawn in the line segment. Sorry if it's difficult to understand me.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely correct! And don't forget, the reason why it's enough to look at 3 points is that Mobius transformations map generalised circles to generalised circles, and any generalised circle is uniquely determined once you know 3 points on it.

Comment: Okey thank you, but I don't quit understand the meaning of "map generalised circles to generalised circles". I am trying to understand how I should think when I get a question like this with Möbius transformation.

Comment: The statement is: Suppose  $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a Mobius transformation. If $C$ is a circle, then $f(C)$ is either a circle or a straight line. If $L$ is a straight line, then $f(L)$ is either a circle or a straight line. Is this clearer?

Comment: Okey thank you! I think I understand now. I will try to do some more similarly exercises.

Comment: By the way @Math, if you find one of the answers sufficiently helpful, click the "accept" button.

Answer (score 2):

No,

Mobius transform send circles to circles (Half plane is a special case of circles)

So The image is a half plane which is created by this points which is $x\ge0$

> You can evaluate $f(1)$ to decide left side or right side

Comment: Could you explain abit further I don't understand. Why should I evaluate $f(1)$? $z=1$ is not even in the circle.

Comment: @Math To Decide which side of the $y-$axis is the image of out of circle and which side is the image of inner area

Comment: @Math In addition I can't believe that the name "math" was not reserved till now! :D

Comment: Haha I was also suprised!